# How to display two columns in a join query that map to same column in second table

Tags: sql, join, group-by, aggregate-functions

I have a table T1 with the following columns

```
T1
----------
ID | Name
----------
1    Sender1
2    Receiver1
3    Receiver2
4    Sender2
```

Table T2

```
T1
---------------------
SenderID | ReceiverID
---------------------
1          2
1          3
4          2
```

I want to join the two tables in such a way that i want to get the sender and the corresponding receiver grouped. I want the names instead of the IDs. How can this be done in one SQL query

Ex:

**Sender                Receiver**

```
Sender1       receiver1
              receiver2

Sender2       receiver1
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
select a.name Sender, b.name Receiver
FROM t2
INNER JOIN t1 a
ON t2.SenderID = a.ID
INNER JOIN t1 b
ON t2.Receiver = b.ID
```

Will give you:

```
SenderID ReceiverID
Sender1 Receiver1
Sender1 Receiver2
Sender2 Receiver1
```

If you want to group those results on Sender1, and have the receiver names in one column (separated by \n or space or something), use a group by on `a.name`. In MySQL for example, there is a [group_concat](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) for the `b.name`'s.

The query then becomes

```
select a.name Sender, GROUP_CONCAT(b.name SEPARATOR ' ') Receiver
FROM t2
INNER JOIN t1 a
ON t2.SenderID = a.ID
INNER JOIN t1 b
ON t2.Receiver = b.ID
GROUP BY a.name
```

Answer (score 4):

Simply join on T1 twice:

```
SELECT TS.[Name] AS SenderName, TR.[Name] AS ReceiverName
FROM T2
    INNER JOIN T1 TS ON TS.ID = T2.SenderID
    INNER JOIN T1 TR ON TR.ID = T2.ReceiverID
ORDER BY TS.[Name], TR.[Name]
```